# java convert hierarchical to flat data

Tags: java, hierarchy

Let's say we have a RDBMS Table like below.

| id | name | parentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Computer | 0 |
| 2 | SmartDevice | 0 |
| 3 | CPU | 1 |
| 4 | Apple | 2 |
| 5 | Intel | 3 |
| 6 | AMD | 3 |
| 7 | iPhone | 4 |
| 8 | iPad | 4 |
| 9 | iPhone11 | 7 |
| 10 | iPhone12 | 7 |

I would like to convert above table to Java List like below.

| id | depth1 | depth2 | depth3 | depth4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Computer | null | null | null |
| 2 | SmartDevice | null | null | null |
| 3 | Computer | CPU | null | null |
| 4 | SmartDevice | Apple | null | null |
| 5 | Computer | CPU | Intel | null |
| 6 | Computer | CPU | AMD | null |
| 7 | SmartDevice | Apple | iPhone | null |
| 8 | SmartDevice | Apple | iPad | null |
| 9 | SmartDevice | Apple | iPhone | iPhone11 |
| 10 | SmartDevice | Apple | iPhone | iPhone12 |

How to convert data structure? I'm currently using Java 8.
If possible, I'd want more generic solution.

If replying this post is tedious(you think :-)), external url is also welcomed. (I mean a link which have best practices.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you facing? How to read data from DB?

Comment: Read data from DB is not main concern(Read from file is OK, if specific file have table structure above). Actually, I just want to convert data structure. I tried Hierarchical data --> Node (which have parent, child), and then loop through, depth3 = origianlTableNode.getParent().getParent().getName();. Which is very inefficient.

Comment: did you solve your problem or still facing?

Comment: unfortunately, I’m still facing it.